# How to force Cypress Schematic to install a specific version of Cypress?

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-cli, angular-schematics

In an Angular project, `ng add @cypress/schematic` installs the latest version of Cypress by default. With the many breaking changes in Cypress 10 and a lack of documentation for implementing Cucumber in Cypress 10, this proves problematic. We want to use Cypress Schematic to install `cypress@9.x.x`. Using the regular `npm install --save-dev cypress@9.x.x` isn't desirable because it doesn't override commands like `ng e2e` like schematics does (instead, Protractor still controls those).

How can I force the `ng add @cypress/schematic` commmand to install a specific version of Cypress?

Comment: You can't, because then the configuration will also be wrong. You need to use a specific version _of the schematic_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the problem is, even the old Schematics versions still set Cypress to install `latest` version in `package.json`. I guess I could change `package.json`'s `"cypress":"latest"` to my desired version and run an `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, just run `ng add @cypress/schematic@<version>` _then_ `npm install cypress@<version>`.